# workbook.close crashes excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open an excel file, print it and then close it by clicking on a button.

It opens, it prints, it closes my file and then excel just crashes.

No warning, it justs closes everythting (2 files) and restart by opening the "version 1" of my files.

```
Workbooks.Open "Thenameofmywb.xlsm"
    
Workbooks("Thenameofmywb").PrintOut

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Workbooks("Thenameofmywb.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Here is a bit of my code, I tried the Doevents method and a lot of others small things but none worked.

Maybe you'll be able to help me.

Comment: Can you attach the code of the Module1.close_xlsm

Comment: It's just a fancy Workbooks.close, it crashes the same.

Comment: Have you tried to check for Excel updates? Check your Excel version.

Comment: Done already, I've also uninstalled and reinstalled Excel.

Comment: Have you tried opening the workbook into a workbook object, and controlling from that?  Agreed, you are not actually showing the closing code so a bit of a stab in the dark really.

Comment: I edited out the bit of code that troubled you. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "opening the workbook into a workbook object".

Comment: Obvious question which you've probably tried already - does it work cleanly when you do this manually?

Comment: Yes, it does work manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I don't think it was code related or not in the code I wrote.

The file that I was opening must have been corrupted.
I tested with "clean" files and it worked.

So I copied and pasted informations from the "corrupted" file to a new one and now it runs well.

Now I don't know how they got corrupted but that's for an other time.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are not making any changes to the file, just accessing it, printing and closing it. So last part should be SaveChanges := false

Also "On Error Resume Next" at the beginning of the sub procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have done the modifications but Excel still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works on my side, using Nathan's idea of using an object.

```
Sub qqq()

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\info\Documents\HHH.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks(2)
wb.PrintOut
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried it and ... it didn't work. Well it worked like before, closed it then crash.

Comment: One more tip. It may or may not work. Yesterday, excel VBA gave me a problem by crashing on a program I had that always worked. I switched my computer off, and my windows or some other update took place, and then the excel VBAs worked well thereafter. The above code I posted works fine on my side. It probably might have crashed yesterday.

Comment: I had a pending update, but it didn't resolve my issue to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried even the following code and it works:

```
Sub hhh()

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\info\Documents\HHH.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks(2)
wb.PrintOut
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
wb.Close

End Sub
```

I commented out 2 lines of code. I am testing with xlsx as a file that needs to be printed. If you are using xlsm, there might be some code there that you have that could be causing an impact. You could still use xlsm but in a way that code from 2 workbooks open at the same time could cause an issue.

Comment: Same as before, it works manually but still crashes when clicking the button.